# Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of uncountable union

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a collection $(A_r)_{r\in\mathbb{R}}$ of Lebesgue subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, each with Lebesgue measure $0$. Consider the set $$E=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{R}}\{r\}\times A_r\subset\mathbb{R}^2.$$ Is $E$ necessarily a Lebesgue subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and, if so, does it have measure $0$?

I was wondering this today, but didn't really get anywhere. Perhaps a counterexample could be constructed by considering an $\mathbb{R}^2$ analogue of the fat Cantor set?

Thank you.

Comment: If $E$ is measurable, it has measure $0$ by Fubini.  But it need not be measurable, even in the special case that $A_r$ is a singleton for each $r$.  See for example this question and answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35606/

Comment: Counterexamples are also given in Gelbaum and Olmstead's *Counterexamples in Analysis*. See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA142&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: A rather extreme counterexample can be found in Krzystof Ciesielski's *Set Theory for the Working Mathematician* (Theorem 6.1.8): CH is equivalent (assuming ZFC) to the existence of a set $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ with $\vert A \cap \mathbb R \times \{y\}\vert < \omega$ and $\vert (\mathbb R^2 \setminus A) \cap \{x\}\times \mathbb R \vert \leq \omega$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E$ is measurable, it has measure $0$ by Fubini. But it need not be measurable, even in the special case that $A_r$ is a singleton for each $r$. See for example this question and answer: [Lebesgue Measure of the Graph of a Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35606) – ccc Mar 29 at 13:38

Counterexamples are also given in Gelbaum and Olmstead's Counterexamples in Analysis. See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA142&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false). – David Mitra Mar 29 at 14:03

A rather extreme counterexample can be found in Krzystof Ciesielski's *Set Theory for the Working Mathematician* (Theorem 6.1.8): CH is equivalent (assuming ZFC) to the existence of a set $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ with $\vert A \cap \mathbb R \times \{y\}\vert < \omega$ and $\vert (\mathbb R^2 \setminus A) \cap \{x\}\times \mathbb R \vert \leq \omega$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$. – Alexander Thumm Mar 29 at 14:23

Comment: I merged the answers-in-comments into a CW answer in order to remove this question from Unanswered.