# Is the graph of every real function a null set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

This question popped to my mind during an analysis lecture:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a (general) function. Is there an $N\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\lambda^2(N)=0$, such that $\{(x,f(x)):x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ $\subset N$ ?

If $f$ is measurable or even continuous, we could apply classical calculus, but what if f is not measurable?

Comment: ok, I edited it.

Comment: See [Lebesgue measure of the graph of a function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35606/lebesgue-measure-of-the-graph-of-a-function).