# Is every curve measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that the set $E=\{(x,f(x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ is non-measurable in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: See:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35606/lebesgue-measure-of-the-graph-of-a-function

Comment: @ploosu2 i am asking for a non measurable set and in the other question he is asking for positive measure. I can clearly see positive measure is not possible that is why i am asking for non measurable set

Comment: In the answer a graph with positive outer measure (and hence non-measurable) is constructed.

Comment: @ploosu2 ok i get it thanks but i am not very comfortable with transfinite induction and the other set theoretic ideas is there something simpler?