# Can the graph of a non-measurable function be a zero set?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If so, what is an example of a non-measurable function in R that has a zero graph (graph is a zero set)? Thank you!

Comment: When you say "zero set", do you mean "null set"? A null set is a set of measure zero.

Comment: yes! measure zero

Comment: Strongly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/35606/259262

Answer (score 2):

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be any non-measurable set. Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be the indicator function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if }x\in A\\ 0&\text{if }x\notin A\end{cases}.$$
Then $f$ is not measurable. But the graph of $f$ is contained in the null set $$\{(x,0)\mid x\in \mathbb{R}\}\cup \{(x,1)\mid x\in \mathbb{R}\},$$ so it is a null set too.