# Lebesgue measure of $f+g$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $f+g$ is a continuous functions on $[a,b]$, then $\mu(\Gamma(f+g))=0$. Here we are considering the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Additionally, $\Gamma(f)$ represents the graph of the function $f$.

I was interested in whether we can say anything about $\mu(\Gamma(f))$ and $\mu(\Gamma(g))$ here? Could I it be possible that $\mu(\Gamma(f))=0$ and $\mu(\Gamma(g))=0$ is equivalent to $\mu(\Gamma(f+g))=0$?

Comment: $f + (-f) = 0$ is continuous, which means that nothing can be said about $f$.

Comment: @MartinR. If we were to impose the condition that $f,g$ are also continuous, this would allow us to say that $\mu(f)=\mu(g)=0$ right?

Comment: Example of @MartinR still works for any continuous $f$, for example any constant, and hence $\mu(f)$ can be any real value either.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\mu(f+g)$, $\mu(f)$, and $\mu(g)$?

Comment: @Michael in measure theory it is common to treat measures (functions of sets) as functions of functions using the Lebesgue integral construction. That is, $\mu(f) = \int f\mathrm d\mu$ and in particular $\mu(1_A) = \mu(A)$ for indicator functions.

Comment: @Ilya : I doubt that is what the asker MATHBOI means.  It would not be consistent with using the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$, or  with the vaguely worded claim in the question that $\mu(h)=0$ if $h$ is a continuous function.  I am guessing that $f$ is assumed to be a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and  MATHBOI really means $\mu(graph(f))$, meaning the Lebesgue measure  in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the set $\{(x, f(x)): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.  This illustrates that simple descriptors of the problem are needed.

Comment: @Michael, you are correct is saying that I am interested in the graph of these functions. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: It seems clear that $\mu(\Gamma(-h))=\mu(\Gamma(h))$. If we assume there are functions $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(\Gamma(h))\neq 0$ then the very first comment proves you do **not** have an equivalence.  However I believe the forward direction holds: $$\mu(\Gamma(f))=0, \mu(\Gamma(g))=0\implies \mu(\Gamma(f+g))=0$$

Comment: @Michael perhaps both of my claims are correct here if both $f,g$ are functions? I found this in another post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35606/lebesgue-measure-of-the-graph-of-a-function

Comment: If both $f$ and $g$ are continuous then $f+g$ is also continuous.